# Need help understanding the "WLOG" part of a proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

> Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be real numbers such that $\sum a_n$ converges and $\forall x\in \mathbb R, \sum_n a_n\cos(\frac{x}{n})$ converges. Let $S(x)=\sum_n a_n\cos(\frac{x}{n})$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to \infty} S(x)=L\in \mathbb R$
>
> Prove that $\forall n\geq 1, a_n=0$

Here's part of the proof that follows the problem:

> $S(x)$ is in $C^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$. Note that since $\lim_{x\to \infty} S(x)=L$  and $S''$ is bounded, $\lim_{x\to \infty} S'(x)=0$. For similar reasons, boundedness of $S'''$ implies that $\lim_{x\to \infty} S''(x)=0$.
>
> For each $x$, the series $S''(x)=-\sum_n\frac{a_n}{n^2}\cos(\frac{x}{n})$ is absolutely convergent and $\lim_{x\to \infty} S''(x)=0$.
>
> We can therefore assume without loss of generality that $\sum |a_n| <\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} S(x)=0$

I don't understand how the last statement follows from the rest. Assuming WLOG $\lim_{x\to \infty} S(x)=0$ can be easily done if you set $a_1:= a_1-L$. But how can you assume WLOG $\sum |a_n| <\infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider $\frac{a_n} {n^2}$ which is absolutely convergent (consider $S''(0)$) instead of $a_n$ and $S''(x) $ instead of $S$ which is the corrispondent to $S$. If you prove the statement for these successions you get $\frac{a_n} {n^2}=0$ and so $a_n=0$ for $n>0$

Comment: Of course! Thanks for clarifying this.